# Can I create a locally accessible only server in lambda?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, lambda

I upload a zip file, and I have the following two files:

```
// server.js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const addRequestId = require('express-request-id')();
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(addRequestId);

app.listen(8000);

exports.app = 'app';
```

and

```
// main entry point for the handler
'use strict';
const server = require('./server').app;

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

As you can see, I'd like to create an internal server that I can use inside my lambda. This times out, and I get an error message:

`{"errorMessage":"2017-03-09T07:52:01.439Z 45210dff-049d-11e7-84cc-8367ae894495 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"}`

The problem happens right at `app.listen(8000)` (i.e. if I comment this line out, then the function runs.

Can I now create a server inside my lambda?

**EDIT**

Please do not comment on how a lambda is intended for a short/one time operation. The question is not about a correct implementation and usage of lambda; I know you are suppose to use API Gateway for routing. Of course this is not the full example. For the sake of this equestion, I need a server to run for the 5s that I need to execute this lambda. Is this not allowed within AWS Lambda?

Comment: Lamdas are designed to run for a short amount of time, and then shut down. It is not meant to function like a traditional server, but rather as a "function" which runs a specific task. This task can be to serve one user a html file, but not hang around and wait for users to come to it.

Comment: Nobody said that's my intention; I very well understand the timeline of a lambda. This is a very simplified example. For my the sake of my example, assume that I need a server to execute this one time application, and after the request is completed, the server dies out.

Comment: Keep in mind that Lambda is meant for short, bring-up then tear-down tasks. In fact the time limit is 5 minutes, which would make it unsuitable for any long-lived tasks. Presently the best solution to expose a Lambda via a web endpoint would be to use AWS API Gateway and have it call into Lambda.

Comment: @Jameson I understand that. I updated my question. For the sake of this example, I need the server to run inside my lambda. The question is not about the correct architecture design, but rather if this is possible at all

Comment: Have you configured the Lambda to use a VPC? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html

Comment: @Jameson why do I need to set that up? My server is intended to be available for local connections only, i.e. I just want to be able to do something like `http.get('lcalhost', ...)`

Comment: It is an interesting question whether or not this is possible, but I suspect you are trying to solve the wrong problem. A lambda can function as a http server in itself, and handle one http request per lambda. If you need aggregation you are encouraged to use SQS or maybe DynamoDB. I also doubt that the ports will be open. What you are trying to do is not the intended use for lambda, but if you don't want to hear this, ignore all the comments.